# alpakka s3 file download problems with Play Framework 2.8

Tags: playframework, akka-http, alpakka

I have a simple alpakka s3 file downloading on top of Play framework 2.8, the code is like this:

in S3 service:

```
def download(link: String): Source[Option[(Source[ByteString, NotUsed], ObjectMetadata)], NotUsed] = {
    S3.download(TraktrainBucket.DOWNLOAD_BUCKET, link)
}
```

and in a controller:

```
          val source = s3Service.download(link).map(s => s.map(_._1))
          val trackName = "track name"
          val filename = trackName.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 \\-.]", "") + (if (track.drumKit) ".zip" else ".mp3")
          val disposition = "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\""
          Result(
            header = ResponseHeader(200, Map("Content-Disposition" -> disposition)),
            body = HttpEntity.Streamed(source.flatMapConcat(_.getOrElse(Source.empty)), None, Some("application/octet-stream"))
          )
```

Also I've an upload thing (it takes an mp3 file, process it with ffmpeg and uploads it to s3 like that:

```
def richUploadMp3(extension: String, checkFunction: (String, Option[String]) => Boolean, cannedAcl: CannedAcl, bucket: String) = producerAction(parse.multipartFormData(handleFilePartAsFile)).async { implicit request =>
    val s3Filename = request.user.get.id + "/" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString + "." + extension
    val s3FilenameTagged = request.user.get.id + "/" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString + "." + extension
    val fileOption = request.body.file("file").map {
      case FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file, _, _) =>
        logger.info(s"key = ${key}, filename = ${filename}, contentType = ${contentType}, file = $file")
        if(checkFunction(filename, contentType)) {
          val taggedFile = audioService.putTag(file)
          for {
            mp3 <- FileIO.fromPath(file.toPath).runWith(s3Service.uploadSink(s3Filename, cannedAcl, TraktrainBucket.DOWNLOAD_BUCKET))
            mp3Tagged <- FileIO.fromPath(taggedFile.toPath).runWith(s3Service.uploadSink(s3FilenameTagged, cannedAcl, TraktrainBucket.STREAMING_BUCKET))
          } yield (mp3, mp3Tagged, file, taggedFile)
        } else {
          throw new Exception("Upload failed")
        }
    }
    fileOption match {
      case Some(opt) => opt.map(o => {
        o._3.delete()
        o._4.delete()
        Ok(Json.toJson(Seq(s3Filename, s3FilenameTagged)))
      })
      case _ => Future.successful(BadRequest("ERROR"))
    }
  }
```

And it works fine for some time but after like 2 days It starts throwing this error:

```
exceeded configured max-open-requests value of 1024
```

and it's not getting away, it seems akka just open requests and do not close it

My akka-http conf looks like this:

```
akka {
  loglevel = DEBUG

  http {
    client {
      connecting-timeout = 5 s
      idle-timeout = 5 s
      parsing {
        max-content-length = 3000m
      }
    }
    server {
      parsing {
        max-content-length = 3000m
      }
    }

    host-connection-pool {
      max-open-requests = 1024
      idle-timeout = 10 s
      client {
        connecting-timeout = 10 s
        idle-timeout = 10 s
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and sometimes I see such thigs in my logs:

```
Response stream for [GET /free/642241] failed with 'TCP idle-timeout encountered on connection to [s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443], no bytes passed in the last 10 seconds'. Aborting connection.
```

what's the problem here not closing connections? How could I monitor it? I didn't even find any way to track open-requests over the time, and how could I fix it?

My alpakka in build.sbt looks like this:

```
val AkkaVersion = "2.5.31"
val AkkaHttpVersion = "10.1.12"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-s3" % "2.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % AkkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % AkkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-xml" % AkkaHttpVersion
)
```

Comment: What resolves it at the moment? Restarting the server? After a restart do you see the `TCP idle-timeout encountered` error? How many such errors do you see until it gets stuck? What else is your machine doing?

Comment: Another thing, on the error you attached, there is a reference to docs, that might explain some of the issues you are experiencing: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/client-side/pool-overflow.html

Comment: Yes, only server restart. There was about 700 'TCP idle-timeout encountered on connection' errors and about 250 another: Response stream for [GET /free/556601] failed with 'Entity stream truncation. The HTTP parser was receiving an entity when the underlying connection was closed unexpectedly.'. Aborting connection.
akka.http.scaladsl.model.EntityStreamException: Entity stream truncation. The HTTP parser was receiving an entity when the underlying connection was closed unexpectedly. That's with 128 connections pool

Comment: It also handles regular lay Framework requests, but it's not a highload project, we have like 10k users everyday, and download endpoints called maybe 1-3 times every minute so it's not under the pressure

Answer (score 1):

Check out the settings in your Play settings made for the backend Akka HTTP server. If your `requestTimeout` is set to `infinite`, which is the default, change that to a reasonable time limit for your app. This may cause a long running connections when things goes wrong in a connection. As noted in below, these configurations overrides Akka configurations.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/SettingsAkkaHttp

> Note: Akka HTTP has a number of timeouts configurations that you can
> use to protect your application from attacks or programming mistakes.
> The Akka HTTP Server in Play will automatically recognize all these
> Akka configurations. For example, if you have idle-timeout and
> request-timeout configurations like below:
> `akka.http.server.idle-timeout = 20s`
> `akka.http.server.request-timeout = 30s`
> They will be automatically recognized. Keep in mind that Play
> configurations listed above will override the Akka ones.

Try using `netstat -tnp` command in Linux to see all current open TCP connections. If you have a test environment, you can start clean and test one functionality (and 1 file) at a time and see which one is causing long running connections. Normally, after the file processing is completed by S3, after 10 seconds or so the connection should idle-out by Akka HTTP per your settings (hence the `TCP idle-timeout...` message you mentioned in your post). If idle-out works as expected for a feature after multiple tries, switch to another feature to test. If this works out well for all of your features that utilizes Akka HTTP, then you need to consider if `max-open-requests` is sufficient for your production environment. This is dependent on how many request you receive and how fast you can process in a given time period.

Also, Akka HTTP is a 'streaming all the way though' library and thus it expects the data (`HttpEntity`) to be consumed before sending more. So, sending just an 200 OK is not enough. Lack of that will cause back-pressure and thus cause new connections to be made until the max limit `max-open-requests`. This could be your situation. Check this out

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html

Common causes of pool overload:

From  https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/pool-overflow.html?language=scala

> Common causes of pool overload As explained above the general
> explanation for pool overload is that the incoming request rate is
> higher that the request processing rate. This can have all kinds of
> causes (and hints for fixing them in parentheses):
>
> - The server is too slow (improve server performance)
> - The network is too slow (improve network performance)
> - The client issues requests too fast (slow down creation of requests if possible)
> - There’s high latency between client and server (use more concurrent connections to side latency with parallelism)
> - There are peaks in the request rate (prevent peaks by tuning the client application or increase max-open-requests to buffer short-term peaks)
> - Response entities were not read or discarded (see Implications of the streaming nature of Http entities)
> - Some requests are slower than others blocking the connections of a pool for other requests (see below)
>
> The last point may need a bit more
> explanation. If some requests are much slower than others, e.g. if the
> request is a long-running Server Sent Events request than this will
> block one of the connections of the pool for a long time. If there are
> multiple such requests going on at the same time it will lead to
> starvation and other requests cannot make any progress any more. Make
> sure to run a long-running request on a dedicated connection (using
> the Connection-Level Client-Side API) to prevent such a situation.
>
> Why does this happen only with Akka Http and not with [insert other
> client]
>
> Many Java HTTP clients don’t set limits by default for some of
> the resources used. E.g. some clients will never queue a request but
> will just open another connection to the server if all the pooled
> connections are currently busy. However, this might just move the
> problem from the client to the server. Also using an excessive number
> of connections will lead to worse performance on the network as more
> connections will compete for bandwidth.

Also review Akka HTTP's example page for S3

https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html

Check out timeouts in Akka HTTP

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/timeouts.html

You can see the detailed descriptions of each of the confid options here

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html

For example, here is the description `request-timeout`

```
# Defines the default time period within which the application has to
# produce an HttpResponse for any given HttpRequest it received.
# The timeout begins to run when the *end* of the request has been
# received, so even potentially long uploads can have a short timeout.
# Set to `infinite` to completely disable request timeout checking.
#
# Make sure this timeout is smaller than the idle-timeout, otherwise,
# the idle-timeout will kick in first and reset the TCP connection
# without a response.
#
# If this setting is not `infinite` the HTTP server layer attaches a
# `Timeout-Access` header to the request, which enables programmatic
# customization of the timeout period and timeout response for each
# request individually.
request-timeout = 20 s
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try, does requestTimeout affect big files downloads? Will it frop any requests over akka.http.server.request-timeout = 30s config?

Comment: @cutoffurmind  the clock starts after the `request` is completely received and timesout when the time is reached but no `response` produced.   i updated the answer, see last link and below in the answer for details

Comment: ok, trying it, also I put None for content-length here  HttpEntity.Streamed(source.flatMapConcat(_.getOrElse(Source.empty)), None, Some("application/octet-stream")). Should I set it or is it fine in terms of akka streaming?

Comment: I set request-timeout to 30s and it made things worth, it started to overflow every 2-3 hours

Comment: @cutoffurmind you should provide the content-length, if known. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.0-M4/api/java/play/http/HttpEntity.Streamed.html

Comment: @cutoffurmind I would suggest to change one thing a time to troubleshoot this. If you change multiple things at once, it would be harder to diagnose

Comment: I gave up debuging it, I just rewrote it using AWS Java SDK and it works fine now